# Micrometer custom metric mostly returns 0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I want to add a custom metric and expose it to on the /actuator/prometheus path.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CustomMetricsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CustomMetricsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RestController
    static class MyController {

        @GetMapping("/metrics")
        public List<Double> getMetrics() {
            List<Double> result = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                result.add(Math.random() * 100);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}

@Configuration
public class MetricsConfig {

    @Bean
    MeterBinder getLoadMeter() {
        return new LoadMetric();
    }
}

public class LoadMetric implements MeterBinder {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoadMetric.class);

    @Override
    public void bindTo(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        Tags tags = Tags.of("application", "panda");
        meterRegistry.gauge("my_load", tags, this, LoadMetric::calculateMetricValue);
    }

    private double calculateMetricValue() {
        OperatingSystemMXBean osBean = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(OperatingSystemMXBean.class);
        double metricValue = osBean.getProcessCpuLoad() * 100.0;
        logger.info("Value {}", metricValue);
        return metricValue;
    }
}
```

If I start the app in debug mode everything is ok. If I put it in container then most of the result of the custom metric are 0.0

Anyone has an idee why this happens?

Dockerfile

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17.0.7_7-jre-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /services/

COPY target/custom-metrics-1.0.0.jar /services

CMD java -XX:MinRAMPercentage=40.0 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError   -jar /services/custom-metrics-1.0.0.jar
```

[image]

**Later edit**

If I restart the docker container several times, sometimes I read non 0 values. Feels like it’s a “race condition” during initialization and depending on who runs first I will have 0 as result or something different then 0.
For example, as per Jonatan recommendation, I made the `OperatingSystemMXBean` a class member. Running the app inside container shows values different then 0

```
2023-06-13T06:33:31.370Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.happypanda.custommetrics.LoadMetric    : Value 0.0
2023-06-13T06:33:32.683Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.happypanda.custommetrics.LoadMetric    : Value 3.2380952380952377
2023-06-13T06:33:36.347Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.happypanda.custommetrics.LoadMetric    : Value 0.25
2023-06-13T06:33:38.673Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.happypanda.custommetrics.LoadMetric    : Value 0.07171029042667623
2023-06-13T06:33:41.188Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.happypanda.custommetrics.LoadMetric    : Value 0.09953550099535502
2023-06-13T06:33:43.564Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.happypanda.custommetrics.LoadMetric    : Value 0.14020329477742727
2023-06-13T06:33:48.971Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] c.happypanda.custommetrics.LoadMetric    : Value 0.046289152908501774
2023-06-13T06:34:04.070Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] c.happypanda.custommetrics.LoadMetric    : Value 0.022086025067638453
2023-06-13T06:34:05.289Z  INFO 1 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.happypanda.custommetrics.LoadMetric    : Value 0.06839945280437756
2023-06-13T06:34:08.793Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.happypanda.custommetrics.LoadMetric    : Value 0.07137758743754462
2023-06-13T06:34:11.564Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.happypanda.custommetrics.LoadMetric    : Value 0.060168471720818295
2023-06-13T06:34:16.481Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.happypanda.custommetrics.LoadMetric    : Value 0.05089058524173028
2023-06-13T06:34:17.761Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.happypanda.custommetrics.LoadMetric    : Value 0.13063357282821686
2023-06-13T06:34:19.803Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.happypanda.custommetrics.LoadMetric    : Value 0.12239902080783352
2023-06-13T06:34:20.936Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.happypanda.custommetrics.LoadMetric    : Value 0.14705882352941177
2023-06-13T06:34:21.901Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.happypanda.custommetrics.LoadMetric    : Value 0.17286084701815038
2023-06-13T06:40:00.641Z  INFO 1 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.happypanda.custommetrics.LoadMetric    : Value 0.011319510406567285
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems more like a Java/JVM issue than Micrometer since `OperatingSystemMXBean#getProcessCpuLoad()` gives you zero value. I assume you would see the same behavior without Micrometer.

A few ideas to fix/troubleshoot this:

1. Micrometer has this functionality (see [`ProcessorMetrics`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/system/ProcessorMetrics.java)), I would use this instead your implementation since it does a few other tricks.
2. I would not do this `ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(OperatingSystemMXBean.class);` every single time, you can move this to a static/member variable.
3. Are you sure you should see CPU load? [`OperatingSystemMXBean#getProcessCpuLoad()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.management/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getProcessCpuLoad()) says:

> Returns the "recent cpu usage"

Where "recent" is not really defined, what if you put your CPU up to some load? I have a service that can create resource utilization based on http requests, you might be able to reuse things from it: https://github.com/jonatan-ivanov/resourceater/blob/main/src/main/java/resourceater/model/resource/cpu/CpuResource.java

**Edit:**
It seems there are quite a few issues around this in the OpenJDK bug tracker: [https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8269851?jql=text%20~%20%22getProcessCpuLoad%22](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8269851?jql=text%20%7E%20%22getProcessCpuLoad%22)

Please make sure you use a version where these are fixed (I would try latest Java 20 today).

Comment: The interesting part is that if I restart the docker container multiple times, sometimes I read non 0 values. Feels like it’s a “race condition” during initialisation and depending on who runs first I will have 0 as result or something different then 0.

Comment: I added a later edit. Seems to me that this behavior is more towards a bug. I saw also that the implementation of the `getProcessCpuLoad` method is native. Should I raise a bug on Java on this? What do you think?

Comment: I edited my answer, please check the currently reported bugs first.

Comment: After reviewing the bugs I still tend to believe that the behavior I see is not a bug in jdk but a bug in micrometer spring boot integration. I created an rest endpoint in which I use the same call to OperatingSystemMXBean. I tried both: created every time and also as a class member. By doing this I don't see  the same behavior as when calling the /actuator/prometheus endpoint: when calling the custom EP I see non 0 values. I don't know the correctness but still. The actuator endpoint is created by spring.

Comment: Further, today I changed the implementation (I copied from what you said at 1). On my local machine, running inside docker container and querying the prometheus endpoint I received non 0 values. Once I deployed the same code on another environment, the prometheus endpoint returned only 0. So same code, the same OS, the same JDK, run in 2 different environments (one as docker on local machine and one deployed as pod) behave in 2 different ways.

Comment: I have a hard time to understand how this can be a Micrometer bug when `logger.info("Value {}", metricValue);` also returns zero value. Not using Gauge properly in Micrometer ([see docs](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_why_is_my_gauge_reporting_nan_or_disappearing)) can cause similar issues but as far as I understand, this is not the case and you get 0 from `OperatingSystemMXBean` which Micrometer should nothing to do with.

Comment: I understand your point. But then how do you explain the fact that when creating a custom endpoint in which the same call to `OperatingSystemMXBean` is done then I see non 0 values ?

Comment: What a custom endpoint has to do with Micrometer? Do you get the same behavior if Micrometer is disabled?